# Cannot restore grub for Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I have a hard drive with some partition for windows (NTFS) and 1 partition for linux and 1 partition for linux swap.
Recently, I tried Norton Partition Magic Pro 8.05 (comes with Hiren Boot CD). It suggested me something related to ExtendedX. I choose [Fix] and then boom, after restart, my grub is corrupted (What's a magic!!!).

When I boot up using Ubuntu Live CD, this is the result of `fdisk -l` on my computer:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4ffe4ffd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2615    21004956    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2            2616       14593    96213285    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5            2616        4619    16097098+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6            4620       11459    54942268+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda7           11460       11982     4200966    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda8           11983       14344    18972733+  83  Linux
/dev/sda9           14345       14593     2000061   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I find and follow an article here: 
http://gadgetmix.com/index/how-to-restrore-grub-bootloader-in-ubuntu-9-10-standard-and-netbook-remix/

But on my computer, when I try `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda8` (which is my ubuntu main partition), the terminal returns error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda8
grub-probe: error: Cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda8.  Check your device.map.

Auto-detection of a filesystem module failed.
Please specify the module with the option `--modules' explicitly.
```

What is that error? How can I fix that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
chroot /mnt bash
mount -a
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda8 # <- are you sure about this? (see below)
unmount -a
exit
```

## About installing grub to a specific partition

If you do this, your boot loader needs to be aware that the partition has something interesting. Microsoft's bootloader is configured by editing `c:\boot.ini`. You do this by first copying the bootloader into a file:

```
dd if=/dev/sda8 of=grub.bin bs=512 count=1
```

Then saving `grub.bin` onto `c:\grub.bin` then add something like this to your `c:\boot.ini`:

```
c:\grub.bin="Linux (GRUB)"
```

If you don't understand any of that, don't bother. Read the next section.

## About installing grub to the master boot record

Grub *is* the better boot loader. Putting it in the master boot record lets you use *it* to start Windows, instead of the other way around.

Before you continue, check your grub configuration file after running `update-grub` to make sure it "knows" about Windows:

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg # used for grub2 users
cat /boot/grub/menu.lst # used for grub1 users
```

Whatever you're using, look for lines that indicate something about Windows, and your `(hd0,0)` device. When you're satisfied, simply chroot like before and then:

```
grub-install /dev/sda # <- note this installs to the "master boot record"
```

When you reboot, Grub will start, and you can pick Windows. If you had entries to boot Linux/Grub in your `boot.ini` file, you can delete them now.

The only downside to this method is that Microsoft Windows *may* delete grub as part of a system update, or general incompetence. Using the ubuntu disk and simply re-running `update-grub` and `grub-install` may be easier than dealing with `grub.bin`

Answer (score 0):

as the how-to stats, change

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda8
```

to

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Comment: Flew, it produces the same error